# C# ProcessExit Event Handler not triggering code

Tags: c#, events

I have a small function I want called when my process exits, however, upon closing (via the red exit button) the function will not execute.

My code is as follows:

```
namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var callback = new InstanceContext(new ClientCallback());
            var client = new MyServiceClient(callback);
            client.Open();
            client.Register();
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (sender, EventArgs) =>
            {
                client.checkOut();
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
            client.checkOut();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HandlerRoutine hr = new HandlerRoutine(InspectControlType);
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(hr, true);
            Console.WriteLine("Click on Windows Close Button");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);

        public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(ControlTypes CtrlType);

        public enum ControlTypes
        {
            CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
            CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
            CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
            CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
        }

        private static bool InspectControlType(ControlTypes ctrlType)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello You choose to end this program.Do you really want to close? :" + ctrlType.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
            return true;
        }


    }
}
```

[Source](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ConsoleFunctions.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this will not work in my particular situation, as I need to access the `client.checkOut()` function within the exit event handler and cannot declare it in a higher scope.

Comment: Call it in the `InspectControlType` callback method.

Comment: How would I go about passing the `client` object to the method?

Comment: Create a global variable client.

Comment: After a bit of fiddling, I got the client to declare globally without throwing exceptions or errors, thanks for the help!